# Formatting the index from the songs package

Tags: sectioning, formatting, indexing, fncychap, songs

I've been using the [`songs`](http://songs.sourceforge.net/) package to generate songbooks. I've been tweaking the package for my needs, but one of the remaining issues is the `\showindex` command. Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[lyric]{songs}

\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}

\newindex{titleidx}{cbtitle}

\begin{document}

\showindex{My index}{titleidx}

\begin{songs}{titleidx}

\beginsong{Amazing Grace}[
  by={John Newton},
  sr={Luke 15:4; 2 Corinthians 4:8,9; Ephesians 2:8; Revelation 14:3},
  cr={Public domain.}]

\beginverse
Amazing grace! How sweet the sound
That saved a wretch like me!
I once was lost, but now am found;
Was blind, but now I see.
\endverse

\endsong

\end{songs}

\chapter*{My chapter}

Hello world!

\end{document}
```

I like to use the `fncychap` package with the `Sonny` style, and it works for all my chapters/sections/indices, **except** for the index generated by the `\showindex` command. Is there a way to hack this command to make it compatible with the `fncychap` package?

Comment: Is it only me, or this example fails with songs-3.1? with error ````/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/songs/songs.sty:44: Extra \else. [}]
/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/songs/songs.sty:44: Extra \fi. [}]````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `songs` packages uses its own internal formatting for its `\songchapter` command which is used by `\showindex`. Adding the following code snippet after loading `songs` works for me:

```
\renewcommand{\songchapter}{\chapter*}
```

Comment: Fantastic, lockstep! I'd never thought of that. Thanks a lot, it works like a charm!